# Login with "function" from "sha512" to "md5"

Tags: php, function, prestashop, md5

I want users to connect to a platform by querying a `Prestashop` DB.
The original file is dependent on 2 `.js` which I also want to undo.

Original file:

```
<?php
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, user, password, salt
              FROM users
                              WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Send email if blocked
            return false;
        } else {
            if ($db_password == $password) {
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);
                return true;
            } else {
                $now = time();
                if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')")) {
                    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database_error:login_attempts");
                    exit();
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database_error:Cannot_prepare_statement");
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

After a lot of work I got to the file below but unfortunately it does not work.
`Prestashop` uses a fixed key to encrypt passwords and the formula is md5(Fixed key _ Password entered in form).

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$key = 'Key with 56 characters';

function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
global $key;
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id_customer, firstname, passwd
              FROM ps_customer
                              WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $password = md5($key.$password);
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Send email if blocked
            return false;
        } else {
            if ($db_password == $password) {
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $username);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = md5($password.$user_browser);
                return true;
            } else {
                $now = time();
                if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')")) {
                    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database_error:login_attempts");
                    exit();
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database_error:Cannot_prepare_statement");
    exit();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: I don't see an actual question here. But you should **stay away from `md5()`** for storing passwords! Do it properly, use `password_hash()` with `password_verify()`.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: The question is how to put my platform to login with the prestashop database.

Comment: Note that MD5, indeed any hash function is not encryption. Cryptographic hashes such as MD5 and SHA256 are one way functions, that is the original can not be obtained from the hash. Encryption uses a key and the original can be obtain ed form the encrypted version with use of the key. In this case thjere is not a key but a salt and a poor one at that.

Comment: Yes i know md5 is a weaker form for passwords but prestashop Uses, but I have to limit myself to this

Comment: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/website-security-access/11169-password-recovery-high-security-password-storage.html I find it quite ironic that they state *"What this product does for you

Best security."* - they really should have thought about *real* password security from the beginning.

Comment: OK, if prestashop requires just using an MD5 (or SHA1) hash then **do not use prestashop**, it is not secure and is putting your users at risk, that is not acceptable. But from their website: "SHA1 with random salt" and that is not secure and not acceptable.